# Store data information in a SESSION instead of using a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, session, notifications

I have a facebook-like notification system where users get notifications depending on who posted/liked/rated at what specific site.

At the moment you'll get notified when you're the creator of some content or you've posted at specific content with this following mysql-statement:

```
SELECT  
n.`id`,n.`site`,n.`site_id`,n.`creator_uid`,n.`type`,
nu.`id` AS nuid, nu.`uid` AS nu_uid, nu.`date`,
nr.`id` AS nrid, nr.`uid` AS nr_uid, nr.`is_read`,
u.`gender`

FROM `notification` AS n
LEFT JOIN `notification_user` AS nu ON nu.`nid` = n.`id`
LEFT JOIN `notification_read` AS nr ON nr.`nid` = n.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON u.`id` = nu.`uid` 
WHERE 
    nu.`uid` != '".$_SESSION['uid']."' AND nr.`uid` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'
    OR
    (
    nu.`uid` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."' AND n.`type` = 'credits'
    )
ORDER BY date DESC, nu.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

Now I have build a friends system and I want to show the activities of my friends as notifications also. I thought of building this into the statement but this statement is loaded on every page on the whole website and I think that this is already quite difficult for perfomance. So going through the `users_friends` table everytime also to "collect" my friend user ids would be even more difficult for the performance, I guess. So I thought of storing this friends user id data in my SESSION once like this:

```
// get friends user ids
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN `sent_uid`='".$_SESSION['uid']."' THEN `get_uid`
WHEN `get_uid`='".$_SESSION['uid']."' THEN `sent_uid`
END AS uid

FROM `users_friends` WHERE `status`='1' AND 
(`get_uid`='".$_SESSION['uid']."' OR `sent_uid`='".$_SESSION['uid']."')
") or die(mysql_error());
$i=1;
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if (!empty($num_rows) && empty($_SESSION['friends']))
{
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {   
    $_SESSION['friends'][] = $data['uid'];
    }
}
```

Now I have an array called `$_SESSION['friends']` with values like "39,2,49" for example. I haven't thought of implementing this now in the notification query, because I wanted to ask first if this attempt is even reasonable or should I take another way to do this? I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something like that but IMHO you need a cache approach.

It depends on several factors but as a general rule I don't use session to store data which should be persisted. In this case I would do something like:

1. Install APC (or another cache system)
2. If you using Laravel or some other PHP FW dealing with cache will super easy, anyway... Do a function to get your query, and within this function check for a cache key based con the user id. If cache key exists return its value, else query your db and save results in cache.
3. Each time you update data for this user friends list, clear the user related cache key.

That way you'll have data persisted and will avoid DB hammering and session workarounds.

Just an idea, hope it helps or inspire. Good look!

Comment: What do you meann by "it should be persisted"? (English isn't my motherlanguage). Thank you, I will look into that. I never used a PHP Framework yet and coded everything by myself with the help of Bootstrap and JQuery. So this is basically and generally the more proper way than storing thousands of data in a session like Konstantin said in his answer?

Comment: Hey @Vay no problem English isn't my mother language neither. Persist data means storing data in DB, filesystem, you know, not a temporariry store. Basically, Session is just something in the Ram memory in the server. Imagine your have a search form in your site and you want to remember the last search for your user, maybe this is perfect to store in session. Because you don't need to store it in your DB. In your example you need to store this info in your DB (persist data) to fetch this data out of this session (e.g.: another user getting this user's friendlist)

Answer (score 1):

Why do more when you can do less and have a better solution ?:)
Why make comma separated string? Just store it as an array. That way you can do all kinds of things like [search array, etc](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) and whenever you need a comma separated string u can use `implode()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Also, **if** you don't need to query database if $_SESSION['friends'] is filled, bring query into the conditional block.

```
if (empty($_SESSION['friends'])) {
    $result = mysql_query(...);
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
        $_SESSION['friends'][] = $data['uid'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I've just edited that part. I'd use `$friends = implode(",",$_SESSION['friends']);` then for the query. So you also think its a good performance solution to use the session to store friends user ids first than to get them every time with a extra join?

Comment: Extra join? Caching is almost always faster than not. In my app i store more than 1000 different things in $_SESSION so that i don't have to query database every page load